# Hover on one image, change another. Multiple first hovers affect one changed image

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a list of product colour shades on a product page.

There is also a large image on the page.

I would like to be able to hover on one of the small thumbnails from the colour shade list and it to display on the large picture instead.

I have the following code but this isn't right. Instead of changing the `mainpic` it changes the image it has been hovered on....

```
$('img[data-hover]').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('tmp', $(this).attr('src')).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover')).attr('data-hover', $(this).attr('tmp')).removeAttr('tmp');

}).each(function () {
    $('<img />').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover'));
});​
```

There is a JS Fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9ch/7/), but as you can see it doesn't work as expected.

Instead of hovering affecting the LARGER pic it affects the same image that is being hovered over.

Live site is here to get a clearer understanding of what I mean:

[Ruby Tuesday Creative Site](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Uc9ch/8/

**Code:**

```
var mi = $('#mainImage');

// this code will do the rest for you
$('img[data-hover]').hover(function () {
    mi.data('prevsrc', mi.attr('src')).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover'));
}, function() {
    mi.attr('src', mi.data('prevsrc'));     
});
```

---

Update:

There seems to be a couple of issues on your page.

a) You have not closed the script tag with `</script>`. View the source and you'll see that the last script tag (the one containing the above code) has not been closed.

b) The code above needs to go inside a `$(document).ready(function() { <insert-above-code-here> });` block to ensure that the DOM is ready and loaded.

i.e. It should be

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var mi = $('#mainImage');

    // this code will do the rest for you
    $('img[data-hover]').hover(function () {
        mi.data('prevsrc', mi.attr('src')).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-hover'));
    }, function() {
        mi.attr('src', mi.data('prevsrc'));     
    });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Why two calls to `attr()`, I'd suggest: [`mi.attr({ 'prevsrc' : mi.attr('src'), 'src' : $(this).attr('data-hover') });`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Uc9ch/9/) (and, if you're using custom attributes, I'd suggest using [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)).

Comment: This seems to work fine in the JS Fiddle but when carried across to the site it doesn't seem to work. Is it because the mainpic is in another div to the colour shades? http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html

Comment: There seems to be a couple of issues on your page. a) you have not closed the script tag with `</script>`. And b) The code above needs to go inside a `$(document).ready(function() { <insert-above-code-here> });` block to ensure that the DOM is ready and loaded.

Comment: Hi, I've gone through and checked the script tags but they all appear closed. Also put in your new script but still nothing? www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/snood.html

Comment: Ok, now the markup and the script code looks fine. But you do not have any element with ID `mainImage` - Please ensure that you have the required elements on the page.